# PHP arrays & variable variables

Tags: php

With an array `$s_filters` that looks like this (many different keys possible):

```
Array
(
    [genders] => m
    [ages] => 11-12,13-15
)
```

How can I programatically convert this array to this:

```
$gender = array('m');
$ages = array('11-12','13-15');
```

So basically loop through `$s_filters` and create new arrays the names of which is the key and the values should explode on `","`;

I tried using variable variables:

```
foreach( $s_filters as $key => $value )
{
    $$key = array();
    $$key[] = $value;
    print_r($$key);
}
```

But this gives me `cannot use [] for reading` errors. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code takes a different approach on what you're trying to achieve.  It first uses the [`extract`](http://php.net/extract) function to convert the array to local variables, then loops though those new variables and [`explode`](http://php.net/explode)s them:

```
extract($s_filters);

foreach(array_keys($s_filters) as $key)
{
    ${$key} = explode(",", ${$key});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s_filters = Array
(
    "genders" => "m",
    "ages" => "11-12,13-15"
);

foreach($s_filters as $key=>$value)
{
    ${$key} = explode(',', $value);
}

header("Content-Type: text/plain");
print_r($genders);
print_r($ages);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$gender = $arr['gender'];
```

What you want there is unreadable, hard to debug, and overall a bad practice. It definitely can be handled better.